# JavaFX Scene Builder shows warning for ListView but refuses to elaborate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I get a warning, i.e. I see something's not right, but I cannot get information what is it. I see the following picture:

[image]

(ListView has warning icon) but I cannot find any place to display list of warnings from editor. The fxml code is following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.hirundo.app.MainController">
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
    <ListView items="${controller.records}" />
    <Button onAction="#onAddNewRecord" text="Add record" />
</VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the complementary `MainController.java` file is:

```java
package com.hirundo.app;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private final ObservableList<String> records;
    @FXML
    public ObservableList<String> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public MainController() {
        records = FXCollections.observableArrayList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void onAddNewRecord() {
        addNewRecord();
//        listView.scrollTo(records.size()-1);
    }


    public void addNewRecord() {
        records.add("New Record");
        System.out.println("New Record added");
    }
}
```

What should I do to get info about warnings in Scene Builder?

The JavaFX version is 18.0.2.

Comment: @James_D Hovering over warning doesn't help, I don't have any message.

Comment: I'm using SceneBuilder 19.0; if I move the mouse over the warning icon and leave it alone for a few seconds a tooltip shows up.

Comment: please explain your problem without sexist remarks (edited to remove)

Comment: Hoving over it for 2-3 seconds can see the warning in my case too. It's `Unsupported by Scene Builder ${controller.records}`.